# type alias declaration for function pointer without parameters

Tags: c++

From [Cppreference - Type alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) I know that following type alias declaration works:

```
using func = void (*) (int, int);
```

How does the equivalent for a function pointer to a class member look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a qualifying class name before the `*`.

For example `using func = void (foo::*)(int, int);`

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/8Khdq7rd1) :

```
struct foo
{
    void bar(int, int);
};

using func = void (foo::*)(int, int);

func ptr = &foo::bar;
```